# Android LinearLayout filling width

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am wondering why this happens :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient" android:focusable="true"
    android:paddingTop="5dip" android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/searchField"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            android:paddingTop="2dip" android:paddingBottom="2dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" android:radius="5dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/search_background" android:textColor="#000000" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/info" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/info_btn" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If I set "fill_parent" to my EditText's layout_width, it takes the whole width of the parent and the button disappears (I guess it is hidden below the EditText).

Can anybody explain me? I would like to get the Button takes its own width and the EditText takes the remaining width.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your telling the EditText to fill_parent, therefore it fills the screen (the whole width, leaving no space for your button).

You want the  button to wrap its content and the edit text to fill the remainder, you can do this using layout_weight property:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="top"
 android:gravity="center_vertical"
 android:paddingTop="5dip"
 android:paddingBottom="5dip"
 android:orientation="horizontal">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchField"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="2dip"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:radius="5dip"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:text="Blah" />
</LinearLayout>
```

(I took your drawable references out to make it generic for other people)

On a side not to make your XML look nice an neat and more maintainable in eclipse:

> Window > Preferences > XML > XML Files > Editor
>
> Line width 120
>
> Split multiple attributes TICK
>
> Align final bracket UNTICK
>
> Preserve Whitespace tags in PCDATA UNTICK
>
> Clear all blank lines UNTICK
>
> Insert Whitespace before closing TICK
>
> Click ok

Then you can fix your XML files, when you have an XML file open CTRL+A then CTRL+SHIFT+F will format it nicely!

Comment: Many thanks ! The missing attribute "layout_weight" + the "0dip" width solved everything.